# custom drag and drop

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-linearlayout

i am a begginer android develpoer and i am tring to build a small soiltare game. 
for dragging the cards i implemented a custom viewgroup which is a "DragContainer" from one of the questions here.
my problem is that when i drag a linear layout. my linear layout holds the cards
with a - margin (to overlap the cards) but when i start the drag the dragged "shadow" is my layout without the margin.
here is an example

[this is the start of the activity, the left is a linear layout with two children and also the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeCZf.png)

when i start the drag this is what i see

[as you can see the dragged "shadow" is bigger(without the - margin)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiJsf.png)

this is the code for the custom drag container(only the stuff that matters):

```
    public boolean startDragChild(View child, ClipData data,
        Object myLocalState, int flags) {
    setDragTarget(child);
    return child.startDrag(data, new EmptyDragShadowBuilder(child),
            myLocalState, flags);
}

private void setDragTarget(View v) {
    target = v;
    onSetDragTarget(v);
}

/**
 * this is similar to the constructor of DragShadowBuilder
 * 
 * @param v
 */
protected void onSetDragTarget(View v) {

}
    @Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    if (mOnDrag && target != null) {
        canvas.save();
        drawDragShadow(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}

protected void drawDragShadow(Canvas canvas) {
    int h = target.getHeight();
    int w = target.getWidth();
    canvas.translate(mDragX - w / 2, mDragY - h / 2);
    target.draw(canvas);
}
```

Comment: If you want answer for `ViewGroup` variant then explain more details. I read but cannot understand your problem.

Comment: try this example https://github.com/pankajnimgade/Tutorial/blob/master/app/src/main/java/activities/list/first/DragTestActivityActivity.java

Comment: i have looked at the examle and i understand it, but it does not help me because it is only for dragging one imageview, not a linearlayout like i need ( I tried with the android "Drag and drop" API and could not make it work, I couldn't see the shadow which was created for the linearlayout. here is a link for another one of my questions for this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35015676/cant-see-new-framelayout-shadow-while-dragging) @PankajNimgade.

Comment: and @ghostman my problem is that the shadow of the dragged Linearlayout doesnt consider the margin set on it. the ViewGroup varient is only to show how I implemented the Drag and drop.

Answer (score 1):

I guess akon does not require the explanation but I would like to tell to the audience of the question. 
The `margins` inside the `LinearLayout` should be intact as you would be moving `ViewGroup` itself, so it's children won't have any issue with it's design, 
Code is also available on the [Github](https://github.com/pankajnimgade/Tutorial/blob/master/app/src/main/java/activities/list/first/DragTestTwoActivity.java)

```
public class DragTestTwoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LinearLayout source_linearLayout;
    private LinearLayout destination_linearLayout;
    private static final String TAG = "DragTestTwoActivity";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drag_test_two);

        initializeUI();
    }

    private void initializeUI() {

        source_linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.DragTestTwoActivity_Source_LinearLayout);
        destination_linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.DragTestActivityActivity_Destination_LinearLayout);

//        source_linearLayout.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        destination_linearLayout.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());

        source_linearLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(source_linearLayout);
                source_linearLayout.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, source_linearLayout, 0);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener {


        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Drag has started");
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Drag has ended");
                    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Drag has entered");
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Drag location");
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Drag has dropped");
                    View source_linear_Layout = (LinearLayout) event.getLocalState();
                    LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) source_linear_Layout.getParent();
                    view.removeView(source_linear_Layout); // This will remove the imageView where it was

                    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) v;
                    if (v.getId() == R.id.DragTestActivityActivity_Source_LinearLayout) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "This is a source location");

                    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.DragTestActivityActivity_Destination_LinearLayout) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "This is a destination");

                    }
                    linearLayout.addView(source_linear_Layout); // this will add the ImageView to the new location where it was dropped.
                    source_linear_Layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Drag has exited");
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }


    }
}
```

> activity_drag_test_two.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="activities.list.first.DragTestTwoActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="4sp">


        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="#ABABAB"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="4dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/DragTestTwoActivity_Source_LinearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/DragTestTwoActivity_imageView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/gohan" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/DragTestTwoActivity_imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/goku" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/DragTestActivityActivity_Destination_LinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="#CACACB"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="4dp">

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

> Output
>   this is how it would look like...

[image]

Comment: first of all thank you for trying to help. but i still have a problem. this code work like charm when the source linearlayout and the destination are written in the xml but for my purpose it is not good because i try to create a new linearlayout in java (only when i start a drag) and it should contain only the views i need for the moment (the cards chosen for this example). when i try to do this when implementing the "Drag and drop" API from android the shadow created doesnt show(the drag works but i cant see the shadow) here is a link to an already open question of mine

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35015676/cant-see-new-framelayout-shadow-while-dragging

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can use standart views for this purpose but it is irrational. It will better to use `SurfaceView` (or if you know OpenGL `GLSurfaceView`).

Comment: why is it irrational? from my understanding SurfaceView is for drawing on another thread so that the main GUI will not be affected... i didn't understand what you ment, could you elaborate?

Comment: Just read as View draws on screen and that operations make to calculate sizes, backgrounds and etc.

Comment: It is hard too to use it for game. Custom realization has better speed as rule

Comment: It developed for GUI and not for another purposes. Sorry for my English.